# Where to write backend coding for dashcode

Tags: dashcode

I am new to iphone web apps and trying to use database(sqlite3) in my iphone web app  but not getting material for getting started with db connection where to do bacend coding in dashcode because ,there are only css ,html and js files and so my basic question is where should do I start with the backend coding .

If any one has solution please do write to me .

Kind Regards 
Parag Deshpande

Answer (score 0):

There is no backend in Dashcode. As you say it is html, css and JavaScript. The "normal" way of accessing data is to define a data source in the JavaScript, go to the library for the code samples to do this and this lets you access xml files.

As far as i am aware it is not possible to access sqlite either from dashcode or even for that matter from JavaScript as JS is sandboxed in browsers to prevent malicious access.

It might be possible to use server side JS such as node or rhino but at that point i would think you were loosing the advantages of DashCode and would be better to move to a more comprehensive platform like xcode or Sencha Touch etc.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 is available as part of html5 localstorage. There is a fair bit of info on the web.

http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Look at session using HTML5 offline storage.

I have used this in a few apps and have been impressed with capabilities and speed.